# Зачем нужен SSH при работе с Git?

Tags: bitbucket, git, ssh, github

Когда я только начинал работать с Git, мне сразу сгенерировали ключи на GitHub. Прошло время, и я совершенно не понимаю для чего они нужны. В BitBucket у меня нет никаких ключей, но я могу создать репозиторий, клонировать его и успешно пушить без SSH. Или делать пулл-реквесты.

Везде объясняют это с позиции работы с сервером, но и тут я не чую разницы. На локалке делаю push. Все пушится на BitBucket. Делаю pull на моем инстансе в DO. Что не так?

Comment: C ключами не нужно вводить пароли каждый раз

Comment: Просто git умеет в разные протоколы. Можно через http, а можно через ssh.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как настроить подключение к удаленному Git репозиторию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-git-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 7):

Заглянем в [ProGit](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B):

Git умеет работать с четырьмя сетевыми протоколами для передачи данных: локальный, SSH, "свой" протокол Git и HTTP[S].

Базовым протоколом является **Локальный протокол,** при использовании которого удалённым репозиторием считается просто каталог на диске. Не подходит для удалённого доступа через сеть, не считая частных случаев с использованием сетевых файловых систем (NFS, CIFS, etc.)

Наверное, наиболее часто используемый транспортный протокол — это **SSH.** Причина в том, что доступ по SSH, как правило, уже настроен в большинстве окружений. Кроме того, SSH — единственный из сетевых протоколов, предоставляющий доступ и на чтение, и на запись. Два других сетевых протокола (HTTP[S] и Git) в большинстве случаев дают доступ только на чтение, поэтому даже если они вам доступны, вам всё равно понадобится SSH для записи. К тому же SSH — протокол с аутентификацией и шифрованием трафика "из коробки". Недостаток SSH в том, что, используя его, вы не можете обеспечить анонимный доступ к репозиторию.

Другой вариант — "свой" **Git-протокол.** Вместе с Git'ом поставляется специальный демон, который слушает порт 9418 и предоставляет сервис, схожий с протоколом ssh, но абсолютно без аутентификации. Чтобы использовать Git-протокол для репозитория, вы должны создать файл `git-daemon-export-ok`, иначе демон не будет работать с этим репозиторием, но следует помнить, что в протоколе отсутствуют средства безопасности. Соответственно, любой репозиторий в Git'е может быть либо доступен для клонирования всем, либо не доступен никому. Как следствие, обычно вы не можете отправлять изменения по этому протоколу. Технически открыть доступ на запись можно, но из-за отсутствия авторизации в этом случае кто угодно, зная URL вашего проекта, сможет его изменить. Короче, это редко используемая возможность.

И последний вариант — **HTTP[S].** Прелесть протоколов HTTP и HTTPS в простоте их настройки. По сути, всё, что необходимо сделать — поместить голый репозиторий внутрь каталога с HTTP документами, установить перехватчик `post-update` и всё. Обратной стороной использования протокола HTTP является его относительно низкая эффективность для клиента. Обычно клонирование или извлечение изменений из репозитория при использовании HTTP гораздо продолжительнее, а объем данных и нагрузка на сеть намного больше, чем у любого другого имеющегося сетевого протокола.

**Итого: доступ к удалённому репозиторию по SSH — самый распространённый вариант настройки удалённого доступа, быстрый, удобный и безопасный.** Настроив авторизацию в SSH по ключам, Вы будете избавлены от необходимости вводить пароли для доступа к репозиторию, сохраняя, однако, приемлемый уровень безопасности.

Автор, а Вы уверены, что у Вас "всё пушится" не с помощью ssh сейчас?

Comment: по http я тоже пароли не ввожу - он сохранился один раз и всё, так и не понял зачем SSH если всё отлично работает через https

Comment: Вы можете писать (пушить) в репозиторий через HTTPS?

Comment: да конечно, `git push` отлично работает, первый раз раз спрашивает в терминале логин пароль и всё