# Как настроить подключение к удаленному Git репозиторию

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote

Как настроить подключение к удаленному Git-репозиторию, через SSH, на компьютере с Windows 7 . И соответственно выкачать содержимое к себе на локальный сервер.

Удаленный репозиторий находится на сервере с git. мне нужно просто склонировать содержимое. никаких пушей обратно. там есть идентификация. сгенерил паблик кей и отослал спец-ту на той стороне. как мне добавить ранее сгенеренный-свой ключ через консоль и подключиться к серверу? какие команды..? Windows 7 на моей машине.

Comment: @NickVolynkin удаленный репозиторий находится на сервере с git. мне нужно просто склонировать содержимое. никаких пушей обратно.  там есть идентификация. сгенерил паблик кей и отослал спец-ту на той стороне. как мне добавить ранее сгенеренный-свой ключ через консоль и подключиться к серверу? какие команды..? Windows 7 на моей машине.

Comment: @NickVolynkin разобрался. остался 1 вопрос. как через консоль добавить ssh ключ, который был ранее создан. не через веб-интерфейс, а именно через консоль

Comment: к себе в гит. на удаленный сервер я передал спец-ту. он добавил. у меня при подключении не цепляется ключ. вот поэтому я и спрашиваю

Comment: @Abyx благодарю)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Установка

Если ещё не установлен, то Git можно взять здесь. Вместе с ним будет unix-like консоль Git Bash.

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/

#### Клонирование через SSH

Пример команды для клонирования через SSH.

```
git clone git@github.com:brockgr/csshx.git
```

В общем случае команда для клонирования по SSH выглядит так:

```
git clone git@server.domain:user/reponame.git
```

Не перепутайте с HTTPS, который потребует авторизации через логин-пароль:

```
git clone https://github.com/brockgr/csshx.git
```

#### Создание ssh-ключа.

На Windows можно как через cmd, так и Git Bash, на *nix — просто в консоли. Но в cmd я не разбираюсь, поэтому привожу инструкцию только для Git Bash & *nix:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user.name@mail.domain"
```

Можно выбрать passphrase, который повышает надёжность, но его нужно будет вводить каждый раз при использовании. Если забудете — ключ бесполезен для дальнейшего использования.

После выполнения команды публичный ключ появляется соответственно в

```
C:\Users\%username%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Именно публичный ключ нужно передавать специалисту на той стороне. (Наверняка вы так и сделали, но всё-таки стоит об этом сказать)

Если всё сделали правильно, то при попытке соединения по ssh ключ будет использоваться автоматически.

#### Если ключ уже есть

То его надо положить в `c:\Users\%username%\.ssh`. Если имя ключа отличается от `id_rsa`, то надо создать файл `c:\Users\%username%\.ssh\config` со следующим содержимым:

```
Host: server.domain
  IdentityFile путь_и_имя_ключа
```

Answer (score 11):

На практике мне когда-то помогла эта статья - лучший пример из всего что я видел:
http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/37865/

В ней полностью показаны клиентские программы для работы с push-ом и pull-ом. У меня лично Windows недолюбливал родной Git клиент, но всегда прекрасно работает с Tortoise (есть в статье).

В ней есть полное руководство по подключению. Не уверен правильная ли это аналогия, но вы можете поставить себе программу Composer и ей подобные, после чего можно через консоль Windows полностью клонировать себе репозиторий с Git-а.

Если же касается более специфичного подключения именно к Git, то эта страница будет полезной: http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/comp/171

---

Добавил, как попросили, кратко содержимое статьи:

Идем на официальную страницу Git http://git-scm.com, кликаем на Download for Windows. В открывшемся окне кликаем на Full installer for official Git. Запускаем полученный exe-шник.

Я рекомендую выбрать "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt". Все остальные опции можно оставлять по-умолчанию. После установки Git нужно перегрузиться или завершить сеанс пользователя и снова войти, чтобы применились изменения в системной переменной PATH.

Далее нужно проверить, доступен ли Git для работы. В любом каталоге даем команду:

```
git --version
```

Если получаем информацию о версии, то Git установлен и работает. Если получаем информацию что программа git не найдена, разбираемся что сделали не так.

**Настройка SSH-ключей в Windows**

В операционной системе Windows генератор SSH-ключей включен в комплект поставки Git. Для генерации ключей необходимо запустить на выполнение файл C:\Program Files\Git\Git bash.vbs. Его можно запустить как обычный exe-шник. Откроется программа "Консоль git". В ней надо дать команду:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@mail.ru"
```

Будьте внимательны, в этой консоли подглючивает копи-паст, проще ввести команду вручную. В качестве email указываем свой почтовый ящик. На запрос "Enter file in which to save the key" просто нажимаем Enter. При запросе пароля "Enter passphrase" и "Enter same passphrase again" просто нажимаем Enter. В процессе генерации ключей в консоли будет выдаваться примерно следующая информация:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Documents and Settings/username/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /c/Documents and Settings/username/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /c/Documents and Settings/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
51:db:73:e9:31:9f:51:a6:7a:c5:3d:da:9c:35:8f:95 myemail@mail.ru
```

После выполнения этой программы, в каталоге C:\Documents and Settings\username.ssh будут лежать файлы id_rsa и id_rsa.pub, они нам пригодятся в дальнейшем.

**Установка SSH-ключа в GitHub**

*Нас колько я помню, эта часть ответа несколько изменилась в современном дизайне GitHub-а, но интуитивно можо найти.*

Сразу после регистрации необходимо прописать в системе GutHub свой публичный ключ шифрования (открытый SSH-ключ). Для добавления ключа, надо в правом верхнем углу нажать "Account Settings".

В открывшемся окне нужно кликнуть на пункт меню "SSH Public Keys", и нажать "Add Another Public Key". Появится два поля - название ключа (Title) и содержимое ключа (Key).

В поле Title можно написать название компьютера, на котором сгенерирован публичный ключ. Можно писать по-русски.

В поле Key надо вставить содержимое файла `id_rsa.pub`. Помните, в каком каталоге они находятся? Переходим в этот каталог, открываем любым текстовым редактором файл `id_rsa.pub` (именно с расширением `.pub`, не перепутайте). Выделяем весь текст, копируем, и вставляем на странице GitHub в поле Key.

После добавления ключа, компьютер может соединяться с GitHub через программу git, и никаких ошибок не должно возникать.

**Работа с репозитарием на GitHub через программу Git**

Начиная с этого момента, пляски вокруг web-интерфейса GitHub можно считать законченными. Далее можно работать только используя программу git.

Вначале нужно сделать небольшую настройку программы git: указать локальной системе git имя пользователя и email. Это делается следующими командами, которые можно выполнить, находясь в любом каталоге:

```
git config --global user.name "YourFullName"
git config --global user.email myemail@mail.ru
```

где вместо `YourFullName` нужно написать свое имя, а вместо `myemail@mail.ru` - свой email. Эти значения используются для логина на GitHub. Поэтому на месте YourFullName нужно указать ваш логин на GitHub-е, а на месте `myemail@mail.ru` нужно указать email, который вы вводили при генерации ключей шифрования.

После этих настроек, можно заливать свои файлы в репозитарий. Переходим в каталог со своим проектом, и даем команды:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
git push -u origin master
```

После этих команд на сервере GitHub образуется копии файлов того каталога, в котором были выполнены данные команды. Далее можно уже делать коммиты, заливки на сервер GitHub изменений, считывания изменений с сервера. Но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: В ответе нет информации, только ссылки на сторонние источники. А ссылки имеют свойство ломаться со временем. Поэтому лучше перенести существенное содержимое в сам ответ, а ссылку оставить как указание на источник.

Comment: К сожалению большинство информации дается с изображениями, вы предлагаете переносить полностью все материалы со стронних источников, они для того и есть чтобы на них ссылаться? Мой ответ расишрю чем можно по возможности.

Comment: Да, и мое личное мнение - это время затратно, тупо переносить содержимое из источников, которым может быть например книга.

Comment: согласен. Поэтому сначала надо уточнить нереально широкий вопрос "как использовать гит на абстрактной задаче в вакууме" до конкретного. )) Но автор что-то не отвечает на уточняющие вопросы.

Comment: Думаю если покопаться в ссылках и предложенных статьях, то все будет понятно, как для абстрактого, так и для конкретного вопросов. Мне кажется ответ не всегда может быть точным и всю работу за вас не сделают, методом тыка тоже полезно поиграться)

Comment: А ещё здесь про GitHub, а в вопросе о нем ни слова.

Comment: @NickVolynkin запредельная педантичность)

Comment: Спасибо! Информации не сильно устарела. При добавлении такого ключа в putty пишет, что шифрование устарело: "Couldn't load this key (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format))".

Answer (score 1):

Вам выше уже предоставили ссылки на скачивание. Повторяться не буду.

После установки потребуется выбрать каталог в системе (или создать там, где захотите), где будет лежать локальная копия того, что есть в удаленном репозитории. После этого в этой директории:

```
git init
```

Не забудьте настроить свой гит через:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

Это особенно актуально для продукта атлассина crucible (для код ревью).

Примечание: опцию --global использовать, если вы единственный пользователь гита на данном компьютере. Если нет, настройте гит под конкретного пользователя в системе

Замечание про настройку пользователя скорее опционально.

Изучите официальную пользовательскую документацию на сайте либо, после установки клиента под windows запустите **git --help** для получения справки.

Для клонирования репозитория в свою локальную папку используется:

```
git clone ssh://username@servername.com/git/folder/here
```

Вы также можете воспользоваться графической версией ГИТа, хотя лично я предпочитаю везде пользовать консоль, мне она кажется более информативной.

Comment: Как можно в своей учетной записи быть не единственным пользователем гита?

Comment: А, поправка: если в гите лежат несколько проектов и для них нужно использовать разные учетные данные. Global - это же для всех проектов одни и те же учетные данные будут использоваться.

Comment: `--global` для учетной записи, `--system` для ОС, но это вроде бы нечасто используется. Для конкретного проекта можно оверрайдить c `--local`.