# Не могу сделать git push из intellij idea

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, bitbucket

Использую Windows 8.1 , Intellij Idea 15, Git 2.6
У меня есть репозиторий на github. На него всё отлично пушится с помощью git bash. Пишу:

```
git push origin master
```

вылезает окно. спрашивает логин и пароль. всё работает хорошо.

решил использовать git с помощью плагина для intellij idea. подрубил два плагина для идеи - git + github. указал путь для git'a в настройках плагина git, нажал кнопку test- работает. Теперь настраиваю плагин github - указал логин и пароль, нажал test - работает.

[image]

[image]

Сделал дополнительный коммит и пытаюсь сделать пуш с помощью идеи. Нажимаю кнопку Комит+Пуш. Нажимаю - вылезает окно с просьбой ввести мастер пароль:

[image]

[image]

Ввожу мастер-пароль, далее система требует ввести логин и пароль (но я же их указал) ну ладно, ввожу в это окно...

[image]
Жму ОК, система видимо обращается к серверу и через некоторое время снова  вылазит это самое окно - введите логин и пароль. Ввожу снова. Тоже самое - через некоторое время требует снова ввести логин и пароль. Как будто я ввожу неверные данные. Пуш не происходит. И в итоге в консоль выдаёт вот это:

> remote: Invalid username or password.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/my_login/qwe.git/'

Что делать? проблемы ранее не было.
До сих пор нужна ваша помощь.

**UPDATE**

P.S. вот создал репозиторий git на bitbucket - через консоль заливает нормально. Переустанавливал  git, idea на ПК, чистил настройки - не помогло

Comment: Настройте ssh и не придется вводить пароль. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468812/181472

Comment: [Следуйте инструкции и все получится](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444780/177345). Скорее всего предлагается ввести мастер-пароль на хранилище, а не на вход в гитхаб.

Comment: спасибо за инструкцию, но я на одном компьютере всё сделал и работает, однако на моём домашнем не хочет ни в какую. постоянно требует пароль (не пароль к хранилищу, а пару юзер-пасс к гиту). переустанавливал Idea, менял пароли, проверял по нескольку раз - эффекта нет.

Comment: Windows? Сертификаты и ключи какие нибудь используете?

Comment: винда 8,1 ничего такого в системе нет. всё работало кстати.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказалось в кодировке командой строки windows.
Когда-то давно я внёс в автозагрузку вызов

> chcp 65001

при каждом старте винды. убрав это из автозагрузки и ребутнув комп, всё заработало