# git выдает "Please tell me who you are."

Tags: git

Пытаюсь залить проект на Github,но получаю такую ошибку ???

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'user@user-��.(none)')
```

Как быть? В первые работаю с гитом.

Comment: а что в ошибке то пишется?

Comment: В дополнение к ответам, поэтому комментарием. Настройте [авторизацию по ключам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468812/) и забудьте про логины/пароли.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Git Вам явно намекает, что Вам нужно сделать. Также он говорит о том, что он попытался уже сам определить, но не получилось.

Скорее всего Вам нужны такие команды

```
git config --global user.email "elik@example.com"
git config --global user.name "elik"
```

(эмейл конечно свой напишите).

Если же Вы на работе это делаете, то лучше написать свое полное имя и рабочую почту.

```
git config --global user.email "vpupkin@company.com"
git config --global user.name "Vasiliy Pupkin"
```

Comment: а я делал без Командной строки (пытался через студиу )жалко придется всеже с командной строкой поработать)Спасибо

Comment: В большинстве случаев командная строка все решает. А гуевые утилиты, какими бы они хорошими не были, часто не могут решить простые задачи.

Comment: да все-же придется с вами согласится

Comment: @elik Git Extensions умеет редактировать эти настройки через GUI

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы необходимо:

```
  git config --global user.email "you@gmail.com"
  git config --global user.name "Vasua Pupkin"
```

Потом:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/vasilukwolf/Random-Quote-Machine
git checkout -b 1-UserStroty-bla-bla
git add .
git commit -m "1-Task-bla-bla"
git checkout master
git merge 1-UserStroty-bla-bla
git push origin master
```

Если что-то в вдруг после коммита не так, и забыли:

```
git checkout -- *
```

Если закомитили и затупили:

```
git reset HEAD
```

Пример нормального workflow:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Пример нормального workflow` больше запутывает, чем объясняет. Откуда-то взялись Dev, юзерстори и эпики. А человек почти впервые видит git, ему рано про это. )

Comment: Dev предназначен для тестирования и разрешения конфликтов. Epic говорит сам за себя. Например миграция  продукта на новую технологию. UserStory - к тебе пришел пользователь, что-то сильно не удобно. Это не баг и не ошибка, но делать надо, иначе человек тратит время. Есть еще Task и Test. Я думаю, этого хватит для нормальной работы с git, если добавить git  commit --addend.

Comment: `Epic говорит сам за себя` – только для тех, кто работает по agile и применяет в работе эпики. Так далеко не у всех. То же самое с userstory.

Comment: Всё после первого блока кода не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Стремление написать эдакий survival guide понятно, но вы слишком отдаляетесь от исходного вопроса и в итоге рассказываете кучу совершенно нерелевантной информации.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете GitHub Desktop, зайдите File-->Options-->Git.
Проверьте, чтобы всё было правильно заполнено, и нажмите Save. Должно заработать.