# Git подключение по SSH по логину и паролю

Tags: git, ssh

Как можно подключиться по SSH к удаленному репозиторию  по логину и паролю?

Файлы ключей недоступны, к сожалению.  Что-то где-то проскальзывало про putty, типо в нём могут храниться пароли...

Comment: может быть поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468812/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E

Answer (score 7):

есть огромное подозрение, что вас интересует подключение по протоколу *http* (в этом случае аутентификация именно такова — пользователь+пароль), а не по протоколу *ssh*, но всё-таки напишу именно про то, что написано в вопросе.

---

возможность/невозможность целиком и полностью зависит от того, **куда** вы пытаетесь подключиться.

если на сервере используется парадигма «один пользователь, множество ключей» (это все популярные системы управления git-хранилищами: *github*, *gitlab*, *bitbucket*, *gitolite*, *gitosis* и т.д. и т.п.), то подключаться надо именно так — указывая (одного для всех) пользователя (чаще всего — `git`) и аутентифицируясь с помощью *ssh*-ключа.

если же это «обыкновенный» сервер с работающим на нём *sshd* (наиболее популярная реализация — *openssh*), и у вас имеется учётная запись на этом сервере, то вы можете подключаться и используя пароль (если это явно не запрещено в конфигурации *sshd*).

---

в обоих подходах используется [один и тот же синтаксис](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a) при указании *url* хранилища:

```
ssh://[пользователь@]сервер[:порт]/путь/к/хранилищу
```

либо (альтернативный<sup>1</sup> синтаксис):

```
[пользователь@]сервер:путь/к/хранилищу
```

например:

```
git@github.com:ocaml/opam.git
```

здесь:

- `git` — это имя пользователя
- `github.com` — адрес сервера
- `ocaml/opam.git` — путь к хранилищу

---

<sup>1</sup> — «альтернативен» этот синтаксис разве что для программы *git*. на самом деле это «родной» (и безальтернативный) синтаксис *ssh*-клиента.