# Авторизация в GIT EXTENSION через вэб браузер

Tags: git

Сейчас при попытки получения/отправки данных на сервер, выходит диалог от GIT EXTENSION, а у коллег диалог отображается в браузерном окне. Как сделать так же?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответа на ваш вопрос не знаю. Но вы и ваши коллеги можете вообще избавиться от необходимости каждый раз вводить юзернейм и пароль. Нужно создать ssh-ключи, зарегистрировать их в вашем xxx.visualstudio.com и перенастроить репозитории на протокол ssh. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468870/181472

Comment: Возможно у вас по разному установлен Git. У вашего коллеги он поставлен из msi. В этом случае он интегрируется с Windows. А у вас, возможно, стоит Portable версия.

Answer (score 0):

Решено установкой новой версии GIT EXTENSION