# Как подключиться к удалённому репозиторию git

Tags: git

Есть удалённый сервер, мне нужно подключиться к нему, чтобы добавлять на него свои правки. Мне дали ссылку на сайт и логин с паролем, третий день ломаю голову, не могу найти решение. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать? Если есть возможность, то можно и статей покидать толковых, всё прочту, всё учту. На вопрос админа, что с этим делать он ответил, что это "ssh доступ к нодам". Но мне это ничего не дало, к сожалению( Если вы мне не подскажете, то я уже и не знаю где ответ искать.

Comment: так к чему вам нужно подключиться, к сайту или гиту?

Comment: ну получается, что к гиту

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468812/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E

Comment: а публичный ключ добавляете в настройках гита (заходите на него через браузер)

Comment: спасибо большое)