# Как удалить пользователя git

Tags: git, github

когда то я использовал git. у меня был аккаунт на github, который я вводил при настройке git. потом я долго его не использовал и вот теперь решил снова использовать, но уже под другим пользователем. я добавил нового пользователя, но когда я хочу сделать коммит - мне говорит, что в доступе отказано и я вижу в логах старого пользователя. как это исправить?

Я делаю такое:

```
MacBook-Pro-admin:backup user$ git push -u origin master
```

В ответ получаю:

```
remote: Permission to repo_name/index.git denied to user_old. 

fatal: unable to access 'github.com***/index.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

На команду

```
git config remote.origin.url
```

выдало все верно, то есть адрес репозитория

Comment: хотя бы свою операционную систему рассекретьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: извините, не думал что это имеет значение. Mac OS

Comment: по идее, роли играть не должно, но на всякий случай не помешает, ведь откуда-то же берётся какое-то там имя в логах. хотя никаких имён быть не должно, если вы корректно ключ [прописали](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422636/178576).

Comment: у меня немного не та проблема. вот что я делаю и что мне выдает: MacBook-Pro-admin:backup user$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to repo_name/index.git denied to user_old.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/index.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: вы бы не могли это в вопрос вставить? в комментариях многострочный вывод, увы, нечитабелен. заодно добавили бы информацию, как клонировали репозиторий, и что выдаёт внутри него команда `git config remote.origin.url`

Comment: спасибо, я немного не правильно делал. сделал через git@github.com и все заработало

Comment: ну, значит, видимо, вопрос можно закрывать с формулировкой «вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой»?

Comment: сори, проблема не решилась. когда я сделал git push -u index master он на github записался старым пользователем((

Comment: помогите решить

Comment: я думаю, лучше задать новый вопрос. в котором изложить, в частности, что такое `repo_name/index.git` и **что** именно вы подразумеваете под адресом репозитория.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, добавлен ли ваш SSH-ключ на GitHub. Он используется для авторизации при push, но не требуется для pull.

Скопировать в буфер на локальной машине (вариант команды для OS X)

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

На GitHub зайдите в настройки своего пользователя и добавьте ключ. Подробнее про git и SSH:

- [Зачем нужен SSH при работе с Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/336505/181472)

Comment: все верно, я добавлял, но числится на старого пользователя

Comment: @Diefair: что добавляли и что числится, уточните? )

Comment: я все делал из того, что вы писали выше. и пользователя тоже добавлял

Comment: @Diefair: "добавил нового пользователя" — куда? на GitHub зарегистрировали? учетная запись в своей ОС?

Comment: да, на гитхабе. потом хотел с компа туда коммитить. но коммитит старым пользователем

Comment: @Diefair: `git remote show origin` что показывает? Нет ли там адреса старого пользователя?

Comment: @Diefair: ну что, проверили?

Comment: я написал в самом вопросе