# как использовать одновременно 2 репозитория git

Tags: git

У меня есть проект. Начинаю я его с того, что клонирую первый репозиторий - стандартные файлы проекта. Потом я начинаю делать проект и я уже делаю коммиты на новый репозиторий. Но иногда бывает так, что мне надо закоммитить на первый репозиторий.

Я добавил их 2 командой

```
git remote add origin .... ... ... -> новый, куда я постоянно делаю коммиты
git remote add index .... ... .... -> основной, надо иногда
```

Когда я делаю

```
git push origin master -> все ок
git push index master -> ошибка
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки

Comment: Кому принадлежит первый репозиторий, который index?

Comment: оба репозитория одного пользователя

Answer (score 1):

вопрос, как я понял, пересекается с этим: [Как удалить пользователя git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478019/178576)

вероятно, к тому репозиторию, который носит условное имя index, у вас нет прав на запись.

если этот репозиторий находится на github и принадлежит **друго**й учётной записи (вашей, естественно), убедитесь, что у **этой** учётной записи **тоже** прописан **ваш** публичный ключ. как это сделать, написано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422636/178576). не забудьте, что, прежде чем проверять наличие/добавлять ключ, надо залогиниться на *github-е* в **нужную** учётную запись.